# What will I need to know to make a mini-camera?

Tags: design, camera

I've recently had some trouble getting hold of a decent car dashboard camera and figured it might be a fun little pet-project to take on.

I'm a software developer by trade, typically for the web. I have dabbled in C in the past and this would make a nice excuse to learn some embedded programming and electronics.

My knowledge of electronics is pretty limited. To the extent where all I know (or think I know!) at the minute is that I'll need:

A circuit with some kind of processor, a video sensor, USB port, mass-storage port (microSD), a few buttons and LED's. Then I guess I would write the software to have the camera start/stop recording on power on/off in looping time intervals that are saved to the SD card, later accessible from a PC via the USB port.

Maybe a little ambitious, but that's the goal.

What will I need to research and teach myself to make this happen? Am I best off getting myself an Arduino kit to test the waters and familiarize myself with some concepts first?

Are there any books that teach-by-example with mini pet-projects like this?

I hope the question is relevant here, didn't want to post at programmers.SE as it feels as though its primarily to do with hacking together an electronic device.

Comment: What level do you want to go into? The easiest way to go about this is to use a board like raspberry pi, panda board or beagle board/beagle bone, hook up a webcam using USB, hookup a microSD reader to the USB port, and you basically have all you want.

Comment: From your post you mentioned Arduino. Arduino uses ATMega microcontrollers which don't have the processing capability and functionality to do what you want (unless you are ok with a couple of frames every once in a while, and even then it won't be easy). The boards I suggested above can get you started fast (especially if you know linux).

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky - Thanks for taking the time to reply. Of the boards you mentioned, Raspberry Pi is the only one I've heard of. One requisite for my project would be that the camera starts recording in <5 seconds of being powered on. Raspberry Pi runs Linux distros, right? Can they boot quickly enough for that? It'd be awesome if one day I could build my own board from scratch so it could be put in a suitably sized plastic casing and potentially sold as a polished product, with that in mind, would Raspberry Pi be the right path given their current scarce availability, or should I head that

Comment: way regardless, for learning purposes etc, then look at more custom solutions? Happy new year, by the way!

Comment: There are many such "polished products" already on the market. Check out, for example, [Supercircuits](http://www.supercircuits.com/). They have many cameras, DVRs, and camera+DVR combos that are suitable for mounting in a vehicle.

Comment: If you tell us some details about how your project is different from http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31304/parts-to-build-a-digital-camera then perhaps this question can be re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following device:

[DM6437 DaVinci Processor](http://www.ti.com/product/tms320dm6437)

This is a complete processor that can directly connect to a image sensor (camera) and produce video. It boots up very quickly and can give you the flexibility to do everything you want.

You can purchase the evaluation kit and get started, and then at some point design your own board. Similar Media Processors can help you do what you want